# syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ']'

Tags: php, yii2

помогите пожалуйста с ошибкой:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ']'

1. in /var/www/u0498223/public_html/coinfactory.pw/views/layouts/main.php at line 53

44                                    <?
45                     $menuItems = array_filter([
46                         // Important: you need to specify url as 'controller/action',
47                         // not just as 'controller' even if default action is used.
48                         ['label' => 'Главная', 'url' => ['/site/index'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
49                         ['label' => 'О Нас', 'url' => ['/site/about'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
50                         ['label' => 'Контакты', 'url' => ['/site/contact'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
51                         Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? '': ['label' => 'Кабинет', 'url' => ['/cabinet/index'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
52                         Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? '': ['label' => 'Партнёрам', 'url' => ['/partner/index'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
53                         if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest):
54                             ['label' => 'Регистрация', 'url' => ['/user/reg'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item']];
55                             ['label' => 'Войти', 'url' => ['/user/login'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item']];
56                         else:
57                             ['label' => 'Выйти ('.Yii::$app->user->identity['username'].')',
58                              'url' => ['/user/logout'],
59                              'template' => '<a href="{url}", data-method="post">{label}</a>',
60                              'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',],
61                              'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
62                             ];


2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()
```

Совсем не вижу не правильно поставленные скобки.

```
44 <?
45 $menuItems = array_filter([
46 // Important: you need to specify url as 'controller/action',
47 // not just as 'controller' even if default action is used.
48 ['label' => 'Главная', 'url' => ['/site/index'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
49 ['label' => 'О Нас', 'url' => ['/site/about'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
50 ['label' => 'Контакты', 'url' => ['/site/contact'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
51 Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? '': ['label' => 'Кабинет', 'url' => ['/cabinet/index'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
52 Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? '': ['label' => 'Партнёрам', 'url' => ['/partner/index'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
53 if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest):
54    ['label' => 'Регистрация', 'url' => ['/user/reg'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item']];
55    ['label' => 'Войти', 'url' => ['/user/login'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item']];
56 else:
57    ['label' => 'Выйти ('.Yii::$app->user->identity['username'].')',
58    'url' => ['/user/logout'],
59    'template' => '<a href="{url}", data-method="post">{label}</a>',
60    'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',],
61    'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
62    ];
63 endif;
64 ]);
65 echo Menu::widget([
66 'items' => $menuItems,
67 'options' => ['class' => 'reset', 'role' => 'navigation'],
68
69 ]);
70 ?>
```

Comment: конечно так писать, ничего не увидешь

Comment: @Naumov  А что именно я не так написала? Вроде специально с подсчётом писала, чтоб разобраться легче было((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если бы форматировали код правильно, то все было бы видно

```
$menuItems = array_filter([
  // Important: you need to specify url as 'controller/action',
  // not just as 'controller' even if default action is used.
  $menuItems[] = [
    'label' => 'Главная',
    'url' => ['/site/index'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]
  ],
  $menuItems[] = [
    'label' => 'О Нас',
     'url' => ['/site/about'],
     'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]
  ],
  $menuItems[] = [
    'label' => 'Контакты',
    'url' => ['/site/contact'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]
  ],
  Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? '': $menuItems[] = [
    'label' => 'Кабинет',
    'url' => ['/cabinet/index'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]
  ],
  Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? '': $menuItems[] = [
    'label' => 'Партнёрам',
    'url' => ['/partner/index'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]
  ],
// ???? где завершение array_filter([
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest):
  $menuItems[] = [
    'label' => 'Регистрация',
    'url' => ['/user/reg'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item']
  ];
  $menuItems[] = [
    'label' => 'Войти',
    'url' => ['/user/login'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item']
  ];
else:
```

Ну и конструкция

```
$menuItems = array_filter([
  $menuItems[] = [...],
  $menuItems[] = [...],
  ....
```

Вызывает отдельные вопросы. **Что** заставило вас так писать?

Comment: а чего его завершать, там вон элементы в массив кладутся и дальше

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Не знаю)) почему-то так решила написать.. но ведь проблема то явно не из за этого... И я ведь завершила array_filter([ на 69 строчке.. Или не там надо? Я не давно начала изучать этот фреймворк, поэтому не совсем понимаю

Comment: даунвоте ну кто if в массив вставляет как вы это себе представляете?

Comment: @Naumov Спасибо большое, исправила, вопрос решён))

Comment: @Naumov эт чтоб потом быстренько разобраться.

Comment: @Naumov Никто. Наоборот, я отформатировал код и показал, что перед `if` нужно закрыть массив и вызов функции

Comment: @GaLana Если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как верный.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Ой да простите пожалуйста, спасибо большое, но я сделала чуток по-другому, но и ваш ответ конечно очень помог разобраться))